# not able to fetch the file

Tags: java, file

I am trying to fetch the file stored in the local system, For that I have written the following code.

Original path I am getting from Database is `C:\Users\Admin\Documents\BulkmailExcelPath\1599203585103000000_4898E400.xlsx`.

If I give directly it is throwing the error. For that I have replaced `\` with `\\`. Still I am getting the same error.

```
            String path = individualObject.getAttchmentPath().replace("\\", "\\\\"); 
            System.out.println(path);
            FileSystemResource file = new FileSystemResource(path);



Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.nio.file.InvalidPathException: Trailing char < > at index 499: C:\Users\user\Documents\BulkmailExcelPath\attachments\1599205942697000000_log4j-application.log                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.normalize(WindowsPathParser.java:191)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:153)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPathParser.parse(WindowsPathParser.java:77)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsPath.parse(WindowsPath.java:94)
    at sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:255)
    at java.io.File.toPath(File.java:2234)
    at org.springframework.core.io.FileSystemResource.<init>(FileSystemResource.java:82)
    at com.util.bulkmailer.service.BulkMailSender.sendSimpleMessage(BulkMailSender.java:54)
    at com.util.bulkmailer.processor.BulkMailProcessor.processor(BulkMailProcessor.java:247)
    at com.kcs.util.bulkmailer.controller.BulkMailerController.sendMail(BulkMailerController.java:109)
    at com.util.bulkmailer.controller.BulkMailerController$1.run(BulkMailerController.java:80)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

If I give the string present in the path variable then it is able to execute the line and not giving any error. What might be the reason.

Comment: "Trailing char < > at index 499"? There seem to be tons of unnecessary spaces at the end of your path string. Maybe you need to trim that.

Comment: Looks like there are unwanted spaces at the end of the file name. Is this coming from one of those fixed-record-width databases?

Comment: Why do you say you have to replace the slashes? I suspect you don't need to, once you fix the space issue.

Comment: yeah, just using `trim()` solved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess based on the error message is that the path contains an invalid whitespace char at the end. You can use a Path object instead of the String that will validate your URI like this `Path path = Paths.get(textPath);`

Comment: Why would they do that, it is already getting validated and that is why they get an exception?

Answer (score 0):

You have trailing spaces at the end of your path. Replace your first line by:

`String path = individualObject.getAttchmentPath().replace("\\", "\\\\").trim();`